# Select Case - Loop patternless series

Tags: vba, powerpoint

```
With nGameSlide
.Shapes("Oval 23").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 192, 0)
.Shapes("Oval 39").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 192, 0)
.Shapes("Oval 61").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 192, 0)
.Shapes("Oval 72").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 192, 0)
.Shapes("Oval 98").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 192, 0)
End With
```

We could use For `i = 1 to 5 Step 1` if the shapes were in a sequence, however in cases like the above, is it possible to use `Select Case`? How would be go about simplifying the code? Would it be something along the lines of `Select Case 23, 39, 61, 72, 98`?

Comment: Make an array of the number e.g. `ovalNums = Array(23, 39, 61, 72, 98)` then do a `For` loop over the array and in the loop, `nGameSlide.Shapes("Oval " & ovalNums(i)).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 192, 0)`

Comment: Or, why not just rename these shapes to some meaning names in number sequence? `SpecialOval1` `SpecialOval2`....

Comment: I second using meaningful names for your shapes.  Additionally, if these are the only oval shapes on nGameSlide you can use the AutoShapeType property to check for msoShapeOval.

Comment: Thank you! There is a limitation in the functionality of the program that wouldn't allow me to name it in a sequence. Thank you for the array idea!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proposal for using Select Case is entirely incorrect.

Building on the suggestion by @Raymond Wu its better to use a loop, however, I'd use a for each loop as its simpler syntax.

```
Dim myNum as variant
For each myNum in Array(23, 39, 61, 72, 98)

    nGameSlide.Shapes("Oval " & CStr(myNum)).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 192, 0)

Next
```

A better approach would be to encapsulate the for each loop in a sub and pass in the numbers to use as a parameter.

```
Public Sub PaintSlides(byref ipArray as variant)

    Dim myNum as variant
    For each myNum in ipArray

        nGameSlide.Shapes("Oval " & CStr(myNum)).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 192, 0)

    Next

end sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Select Case`

```
For Each Shape in Shapes
Select Case Shape.Name
    Case "Oval 23", "Oval 39", "Oval 61", "Oval 72", "Oval 98"
        'Do something
    Case Else
        'Do nothing
End Select
Next Shape
```

There is some merit to use this method, i.e. you can easily add or change a procedure of a particular `shape`.

The caveat is it would loop through all `Shapes`, so may be a little slower than using the array() method as suggested by @Raymond, if there are more than 5 shapes in the slide.